# How to get and set excel column width through c# excel interop

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am using excel interop in creating excel. Now, I have to get the size of a column as basis of what the next column's size would be. I tried the following code:

```
width = xlWorksheet.Range[xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 4], xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 11]].Width;
xlWorksheet.Columns[5].ColumnWidth = width;

width_of_first_col = xlWorksheet.Range[xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1], xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1]].Width;
xlWorksheet.Columns[6].ColumnWidth = width_of_first_col;
```

The result should be column 4 and column 5 have the same size, as well as column 1 and 6. But this is not true to what the exact result looks like.

What is the best thing to do to set the with of a cell to another cell. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Excel manages width of columns in multiple ways.

- The **Columnwidth** property returns or sets the width of columns as the number of characters of the normal font that can be accommodated in one column. Please refer to this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214123).
- The **width** property gives the width in points of a range as specified [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range_members%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`Range.Width` is a read-only property, which give you the width in points.

`Range.ColumnWidth` is a read/write property, which gives you the width in what I like to call character units. A character unit represents the width of the character `0` under the font type and size as defined by the `Normal` style of the workbook.

In your case, since you do not need to calculate the width in points, just use `.ColumnWidth` all along.

```
n = ColumnNumberOfYourChoice;
width = xlWorksheet.Range.Columns.Item[n].ColumnWidth;
xlWorksheet.Columns[5].ColumnWidth = width;

width_of_first_col = xlWorksheet.Range.Columns.Item[1].ColumnWidth;
xlWorksheet.Columns[6].ColumnWidth = width_of_first_col;
```

Note from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.columnwidth?view=excel-pia):

> If all columns in the range have the same width, the ColumnWidth property returns the width. If columns in the range have different widths, this property returns Null.