# How can I get column width via openxml and c#

Tags: c#, openxml

My task is parse an excel file and converted it to web table.
To achieve that objective, I need the column numbers, width of each column, row numbers, and each cell and cell property within the row.

So far, I can get the rows, the cells, the cell property such as border,font, and so on. But I can't get the column width.

When I open the excel file and get columns by following code

```
Columns columns = sheet.Descendants<Columns>().FirstOrDefault()
```

But, sometimes I can get it, sometimes the value is null.

I read the excel file by openxml tools. The following code is not always there.

```
Columns columns1 = new Columns();
Column column1 = new Column(){ Min = (UInt32Value)7U, Max = (UInt32Value)7U, Width = 39.6328125D, CustomWidth = true };
columns1.Append(column1);
```

If you open an empty excel file and do not change column width, then you save it. The code is not there.

So my question is how can I get the column width?

Comment: Can you use Excel interop? 
If so, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32392541/how-to-get-and-set-excel-column-width-through-c-sharp-excel-interop

Comment: What technology are you using to parse the xml ? It looks like Open Xml SDK, but i may be wrong...

Comment: @ vasil oreshenski, I'm using open xml sdk

Answer (score 2):

A column width can have either the default width or custom width. As you state, the custom width can be read from [Column.Width property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.column.width.aspx). If the default column width is set, it can be read from [SheetFormatProperties Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.sheetformatproperties(v=office.14).aspx). However, if `DefaultColumnWidth` property is set to null, [The default column width is 8.43 characters](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-column-width-and-row-height-72f5e3cc-994d-43e8-ae58-9774a0905f46).

To get the `DefaultColumnWidth` :

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true))
{
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
    IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
    string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
    Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;

    var sheetFormatProps = workSheet.SheetFormatProperties;
    var defaultColWidth = sheetFormatProps.DefaultColumnWidth;
    if (defaultColWidth == null)
    {
        defaultColWidth = 8.43;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't an aswer to the question, not even close.

Comment: @Gábor the answer clearly explains how to get a column width.

Comment: Sorry, it does not. Stating that you need to read `Column.Width` is merely an assumption without actually trying it out. And, sadly, it's an incorrect one because there is no `Column` unless you customized it in the first place: a plain XLSX has no `Column` items at all. While you did show how to get the default column size, you couldn't answer how to read the width of a _particular column_ because, actually, there's no way. Rest assured that I didn't want to harrass you :-), just to leave a warning for the next poor soul who has to spend hours to arrive at the same sad conclusion.

Comment: Again, kindly read the answer. The first line says it either has custom width or default width. So there are no assumptions. An empty xlxs won’t have any custom widths, something i guess is fundamental and doesn’t need to be mentioned verbose. In case u don’t find the custom width you need to check for default widths. Which again the answer covers. Also note the OP edited the question post my answer. Nevertheless the answer covers how to know the width of a column. A little patience while reading shall do it :). Good luck!